# Difference between connect and bind in bootstrap : Netty

Tags: java, netty

I am newbie to Netty framework and trying to understand its internals.
My question is about `BootStrap` class for client and for connectionless protocols.
I see two methods `Connect( defined in BootStrap )` and `Bind ( defined in AbstractBootStrap )`

Since `Bootstrap` is child of `AbstracBootStrap` , it also has `Bind` method.
I understand use `Connect()` to connect to remote server , why is `Bind()` needed for ?

Comment: The bind() method is useful for connectionless transports such as datagram (UDP

Answer (score 2):

You can first bind the local port/ip and the connect to the remote port. This basically allows you to do this in two steps.

Answer (score 2):

bind and connect are TCP/IP concepts, which Netty uses because it is a server.

**Connect** is how you connect a local machine to a remote machine.

**Bind** is how you get the server to listen for remote connections on a port.

Check out this Oracle tutorial on Networking Basics:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html